# What was Thanos referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, when Thanos and Gamora are on Vormir, Thanos mentions that he passed up his destiny once and that he wasn't going to do it again. He said this because

> he was explaining to Gamora why he **has** to kill her.

What "other destiny" was Thanos referring to?

Comment: I thought it referred to not enacting his plan on Titan.

Comment: @Herohtar Was it? I don't remember him giving any context at that time, and I don't think he uses any specific verbiage that's consistent between conversations (i.e., between the convo where he mentions his initial plans for saving Titan, and his convo with Gamora on Vormir). Are you basing your thoughts/opinion off anything specific?

Comment: I've only seen the movie once so far so I may have missed some things and am not certain, which is why I didn't post it as an answer, but it seemed to me that he meant his destiny was to save Titan, but his idea was rejected and he did nothing, thus by not going ahead with it by force he "passed up" his destiny and Titan eventually fell. (Basically my thought came from the backstory about Titan that was revealed in the later scene)

Comment: @Herohtar Right.. the only thing that caught me up was that Thanos didn't really have a choice with Titan.. the way he portrayed it was that he had proposed the idea, everyone rejected it, and then thought him to be a mad man for it. So, maybe he should have said "I failed to *follow/pursue* my destiny once, and I won't do it again", to be a bit more accurate (if that's in fact what he was referring to).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the movie, the people on his home Planet did nothing to resolve the issue of overpopulation on Thanos's home planet.

And in a scene where he uses the Reality Stone to show how Titan was, he also says that how when he suggested to kill half the population, he was branded a mad man and sent to exile. He did nothing and that brought about the ruin of his Planet.

I think this is what Thanos is referring to when he says that he will face his destiny this time.

Comment: As I recall the ruin of Titan came not because Thanos failed to act, but because the rulers of the planet did not heed his warning.

Comment: I think Thanos's statement does not explicitly imply that. But when you see the state of his planet, that's the only conclusion. He could've gone for the Infinity Stones at that point of time as well, but he didn't, which resulted badly for his home Planet.

Comment: I recall him saying specifically when talking about the downfall of his planet that he urged the leaders to act but they called him 'a madman'.